# Why does getdata have a field for the number of inventory entries?

Tags: protocol, network

After a node receives an `inv` message, you can get the data for each tx/block hash using `getdata`:

> getdata - Request a single block or transaction by hash.

So if you can only get one tx or block at a time, what's the purpose of having a field in the `getdata` message for the *number of entries* you are requesting?

> ```
> Field Size  Description   Data type   Comments
> ----------  ------------  ----------  -------------
> ?           count         var_int     Number of inventory entries
> 36x?        inventory     inv_vect[]  Inventory vectors
> ```

---

https://wiki.bitcoin.com/w/Network#Messages
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#getdata

Answer (score 1):

The documentation you are linking too is wrong, the [bitcoin developer reference](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#getdata) indicates you can send multiple inventories inside of a `GetData` message.

Comment: It's not wrong, but maybe not very client. The `[]` after `inv_vect` indicates it's about an array of entries.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'very client' you mean varies by client version?

Comment: Sorry, "very clear" !

Comment: Sorry, I was talking about the protocol spec copy-paste. The statement "Request a single block or transaction by hash" is clearly wrong.